# How to add data filter in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have 2 or more dropdown list in my JSP page...Now in my servlet I want to pass the two value of the selected items in two dropdown list and query this value to the database. I dont want to have this many method about the all possible combinations and have all of this combination a one class. Now how can I able to pass the two value of the selected items in the ddl?

here's my try

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        int SelectedOrg;
        int SelectedSec;
        String FilterByOrg = req.getParameter("OrgFilter");
        String FilterBySec = req.getParameter("SectorFilter");
        if (!"11".equals(FilterByOrg) && !"11".equals(FilterBySec))
        {       
                SelectedOrg = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("OrgFilter"));
                SelectedSec = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("SectorFilter"));
                List<OrganizationItems> orgItems = new ViewAllOrganizations().findEMSOnly(SelectedOrg, SelectedSec);
                req.setAttribute("orgItems", orgItems);
                jsp.forward(req, resp);
        }
        else
        {
            List<OrganizationItems> orgItems = new ViewAllOrganizations().findAll();
            req.setAttribute("orgItems", orgItems);
            jsp.forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
```

Here's my JSP page

```
 <form method="GET">
                            <div>
                                <span>Organization: </span> <select name="OrgFilter">
                                <option value="11">Organization Type</option>
                                <option value="22">All</option>
                                    <option value="1">Emergency Medical Service</option>
                                    <option value="3">Fire Suppression Group</option>
                                    <option value="4">Medical Facilities</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span>Sector: </span> <select name="SectorFilter" onchange="submit()">
                                <option value="11">Sector Type</option>
                                    <option value="22">All</option>
                                    <option value="1">NA</option>
                                    <option value="2">Government</option>
                                    <option value="3">Private</option>
                                    <option value="4">Volunteer</option>
                                    <option value="5">Corporate/Industrial</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

After this I have my table below the form tag that displays the results

Comment: What's your question exactly? What do you mean by *"how can I able to pass the two value of the selected items in the ddl?"*?

Comment: For example the value of the selected item in drop down lists are 1 and 2. Now i want to query it like select * from table where field1 = ? and field2 = ?.

Comment: So, you're asking basically how to execute parameterized SQL queries in Java? Read [the JDBC tutorial about prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: that not my main concern. I am trying to have filters in my data based on the user' selected item in my dropdown lists

Comment: But you already have code above to get these two parameters (`SelectedOrg` and `SelectedSec`). Does that work? If not, what's the problem? If it works, you just need to execute the SQL query using these two parameters as parameters of the query. To know how to do that, read the tutorial.

Comment: I cant figure out the problm..theres nothing wrong with the query...

Comment: the page still displays all items in the table. s my filters are not working

Comment: How could we help? You don't show the code which applies the filter. Are you sure both FilterByOrg and FilterBySec are different from "11"? Have you stepped through the code using a debugger?

Comment: what do you mean if different from 11?

Comment: You're applying the filter only `if (!"11".equals(FilterByOrg) && !"11".equals(FilterBySec))`. So if any of those is equal to `"11"`, the filter won't be applied, and all the items will be displayed.

Comment: im using the && so it must be both right?

Comment: The condition is true if FilterByOrg is different from "11" AND FilterBySec is different from "11", so they must be both different from `"11"`. So if at least one of them is equal to `"11"`, the else clause will be executed.